# Data after backslash in URL and preventing the default

Tags: php

I'm trying to get the data from a URL and preventing the default action it has.

Let me explain using a example.

**URL**: http://mywebsite.com/team/myteam/console/info

Where `team/myteam/console` is the data I want to send through.

But, if I were to use this right now it would act as if it were folders which they aren't.

Could anyone help me out with this one?

Comment: mod_rewirte htaccess are your friends

Comment: @donald123 I will look into this, thanks!